# Getting metrics graph to display the graph in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I'm using vue and laravel and I'm trying to get metrics-graphics chart to display a chart. The issue I'm having is that it seems that the data gets
pulled through but it doesn't seem display and there is nothing in the console.

Here is my code

```
    d3.json('/api/chart', function(data) {
        console.log('im here');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = MG.convert.date(data[i], 'date');
        }

        MG.data_graphic({
            title: "Basic Brushing & Zooming",
            description: "This is a simple example of brushing and zooming. You can set 'brush' as 'xy', 'x', 'y' to specify the axis(es) that may be brushed.",
            data: data,
            top: 70,
            width: 600,
            height: 240,
            right: 40,
            missing_is_hidden: true,
            target: '#chart',
            brush: 'xy',
        });
    });
```

and in my Network tab this is what my preview shows

```
chart: "[{"date":"2014-01-01","value":150000000},{"date":"2014-01-02","value":168799730},{"date":"2014-01-03","value":179473940}]"
```